# Missing /usr/include in OS X El Capitan

Tags: macos, osx-el-capitan

I was trying to build an app which depends on `PJSIP` lib which should have some headers in `/usr/include`. But there is no `/usr/include` folder, and I can't create one even my account has administrator rights.

How can be `include` folder, activated/created/restored ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Update (12 Feb 2016):**

I finally installed El Capitan and can now confirm that Ondřej Čertík's answer is correct. I strongly recommend installing the command line developer tools instead of disabling SIP.

As Ondřej noted, simply installing Xcode will not install all of the command line developer tools. You must execute `xcode-select --install` in Terminal.

---

**Original post (5 Dec 2015):**

Write access to /System, /bin, /sbin, /usr, /etc, /tmp and /var has been disabled by default in El Capitan, even for root. This is due to the new [Security Integrity Protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection) feature.

To [disable SIP](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection.html), boot into recovery mode and execute the command `csrutil disable` in Terminal.

Disclaimer: I have not tested this myself since I have not yet upgraded to El Capitan.

Comment: Confirmed ! Works in El Capitan too

Comment: I've already figure it out, and forgot to answer to my own question. I'll accept yours as it's correct.

Comment: On my system, the proper fix was to just install the `/usr/include` using `xcode-select --install` and leave SIP enabled. See my answer below for more info.

Answer (score 14):

By default, when you install Xcode ("developer tools") from the App Store on El Capitan, it does not install the "command line developer tools" which include the `/usr/include`. To install the "command line developer tools", execute `xcode-select --install`, it will prompt you about whether you want to get Xcode+command line tools from the App Store (but I already have Xcode installed from the App Store and it apparently does not include the command line utilities), so I selected "install" and that installed `/usr/include` among other things.

As to the System Integrity Protection (SIP), leave that enabled, as that seems to be a good thing. The reason `xcode-select --install` managed to install into the protected `/usr` directory is probably because `xcode-select` is whitelisted by SIP.

Comment: I thought Xcode 8.x included the command line tools, but just needed to do this on a fresh install of **MacOS Sierra**. I installed Xcode first, then still had to do the `xcode-select --install` to get the tools.